# translation missing: ar.activerecord.errors.models.address.attributes.area.required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml

Im internationalizing a website, and I found a problem that looking into the guides wont fix for me.

When a form is left unfilled, I'm getting this error:

> translation missing:
> ar.activerecord.errors.models.address.attributes.area.required

I followed the guides and inserted the following in the YAML translation file:

```
activerecord:
      attributes:
        address:
          area: "منطقة"
          street_name: "اسم/رقم الشارع"
      errors:
        models:
          address:
            attributes:
              area:
                required: "يجب أن تختار منطقة من المناطق الموجودة في قائمة المناطق"
        messages:
          required: يجب أن تختار منطقة من المناطق الموجودة في قائمة المناطق
          record_invalid: 'فشل التحقّق من: %{errors}'
```

**Update:** As shown in the file, I also tried adding `required` under `messages` but still getting the same error

I'm still getting the same error though. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is `errors:` nested under `activerecord:`?

Comment: yes, activerecord: errors:

Comment: Yes I have errors: messages:
But under those I dont have required:
Bear in mind that I want the error message for area.required only not all the required fields

Comment: Tried this. Nothing as well. Will update the question with what  I tried.

Comment: Is the yaml file properly indented?

Comment: Yes I suppose. Its working for all the other things except for this error

Answer (score 1):

Does the YAML file has `ar` as its main key? It seems to be missing.

```yaml
ar:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I upvoted :) But no its there. Just didnt put it here

Comment: Does `I18n.load_path` include the YAML file's path?

Comment: yes. All the normal translations work fine. Im still getting this error though. So Im sure its smt that has to do with this particular translation